# No me ejecutan los bloques anónimos(sean estaticos o no) en Java

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, cmd, static

Tengo un problema que al ejecutar bloques anónimos estos no me funcionan en el IDE Netbeans, pero cuando los ejecuto desde comandos si los trata normal. Aquí lo que me pasa.

Tengo esta clase:

```
public class Main {


static int i;
static
{
    i = 5;
    System.out.println("hola");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Main a = new Main();
    System.out.println(Main.i);
}}
```

Al ejecutarlo me debería arrojar un hola y luego un 5 pero no, no me arroja nada. Aquí lo que me bota si lo ejecuto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahora si ejecuto la clase desde la linea de comandos, si me funciona normal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se a que se deba esto, ya e desinstalado el jdk y netbeans y vuelto a instalar pero sigue pasando lo mismo, tambien agrege las directivas de donde se encuentra javac a las variables de entorno pero sigue sin ejecutarme los bloques anonimos desde Netbeans.

Comment: Acabo de ejecutarlo en Netbeans y me corre normal, muestra hola luego el 5